# C: Undefined reference to `dlopen`/`dlsym` despite adding `-ldl` flags

Tags: c, makefile, dlopen

**TL;DR:** I'm working on a C exercise that uses `dlfcn.h` to open shared libraries.  Despite adding (what I think are) the correct flags based on other posts, I'm still  getting `undefined reference to` errors for `dlopen`, `dlsym` and a few other functions defined in `dlfcn.h` (error message and make-file are included below).

I've obv included the following at the start of my `.c` file: `#include <dlfcn.h>`

What am I doing wrong?

**Detailed version:**

I'm working on [exercise 30 of `Learn C The Hard Way`](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex30.html) and am puzzled as to what else I need to do in order to get the `libex29_tests.c` program (very last section of code on the page) to compile correctly.  As you can probably tell, shared libraries/makefiles/compiler flags are new to me at the moment.

What I've tried so far: Based on the following posts, I've tried adding the `-ldl` flag by adding `LIBS=-ldl fPIC` and/or `LDFLAGS+=-ldl` to various parts of my Makefile but am still having issues.  The version of the makefile in the book (included below, as reference) does include an `-ldl` flag albeit via slightly different syntax.  In any case, I continue to get the same error message.

- [Linux c++ error: undefined reference to 'dlopen'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956640/linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-dlopen)
- [g++ cannot link to libdl even with -ldl flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201849/g-cannot-link-to-libdl-even-with-ldl-flag)
- [undefined reference to 'dlopen' in installing phonetisaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787117/undefined-reference-to-dlopen-in-installing-phonetisaurus)
- [C++: Undefined symbols when loading shared library with dlopen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762910/c-undefined-symbols-when-loading-shared-library-with-dlopen)

Any suggestions?

---

These are the errors that I get.  These errors assume the version of the `makefile` included below.  However, as I'd mentioned, changing the syntax for the `-ldl` flag results in virtually the same error message(s).

```
~/.../lchw/ex30_automated$ make
cc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  -fPIC   -c -o src/libex29.o src/libex29.c
src/libex29.c: In function ‘fail_on_purpose’:
src/libex29.c:42:33: warning: unused parameter ‘msg’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int fail_on_purpose(const char *msg)
                                 ^
ar rcs build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a src/libex29.o
ranlib build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a
cc -shared -o build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.so src/libex29.o
cc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG  build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a    tests/libex29_tests.c   -o tests/libex29_tests
In file included from tests/libex29_tests.c:1:0:
tests/libex29_tests.c: In function ‘main’:
src/minunit.h:14:38: warning: parameter ‘argc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
 #define RUN_TESTS(name) int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {\
                                      ^
tests/libex29_tests.c:64:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘RUN_TESTS’
 RUN_TESTS(all_tests);
 ^
/tmp/dchaudh/ccwzxpC3.o: In function `check_function':
/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudh/wc/lchw/ex30_automated/tests/libex29_tests.c:10: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudh/wc/lchw/ex30_automated/tests/libex29_tests.c:11: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/tmp/dchaudh/ccwzxpC3.o: In function `test_dlopen':
/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudh/wc/lchw/ex30_automated/tests/libex29_tests.c:23: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/tmp/dchaudh/ccwzxpC3.o: In function `test_dlclose':
/home/dchaudh/Dropbox/dchaudh/wc/lchw/ex30_automated/tests/libex29_tests.c:46: undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tests/libex29_tests] Error 1
```

---

Here's the latest `makefile` as per the book.  It does include the `-ldl` flag, as you can see on the second line.

```
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG $(OPTFLAGS)
LIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)
PREFIX?=/usr/local

SOURCES=$(wildcard src/**/*.c src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

TEST_SRC=$(wildcard tests/*_tests.c)
TESTS=$(patsubst %.c,%,$(TEST_SRC))

TARGET=build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a
SO_TARGET=$(patsubst %.a,%.so,$(TARGET))

# The Target Build
all: $(TARGET) $(SO_TARGET) tests

dev: CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Isrc -Wall -Wextra $(OPTFLAGS)
dev: all

$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $@ $(OBJECTS)
    ranlib $@

$(SO_TARGET): $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)

build:
    @mkdir -p build
    @mkdir -p bin

# The Unit Tests
.PHONY: tests
tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
tests: $(TESTS)
    sh ./tests/runtests.sh

valgrind:
    VALGRIND="valgrind --log-file=/tmp/valgrind-%p.log" $(MAKE)

# The Cleaner
clean:
    rm -rf build $(OBJECTS) $(TESTS)
    rm -f tests/tests.log
    find . -name "*.gc*" -exec rm {} \;
    rm -rf `find . -name "*.dSYM" -print`

# The Install
install: all
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/
    install $(TARGET) $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/lib/

# The Checker
BADFUNCS='[^_.>a-zA-Z0-9](str(n?cpy|n?cat|xfrm|n?dup|str|pbrk|tok|_)|stpn?cpy|a?sn?printf|byte_)'
check:
    @echo Files with potentially dangerous functions.
    @egrep $(BADFUNCS) $(SOURCES) || true
```

Answer (score 7):

`${LIBS}` (and your `-ldl`) is nowhere used in the makefile. It seems, you are using builtin rules for compiling and can use the `LDLIBS` instead of `LIBS` for the name of this variable.

Beside this, the

```
  tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)
```

in your example is wrong because `TARGET` is a library which must go into `(LD)LIBS`.

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
build:
    @mkdir -p build
```

is not sane either.  This will break in parallel builds (`$(OBJECTS)` should depend on `build`) and will cause unneeded builds (`build` is a directory and alterered by every compile/link operation).  Plain `build` will be problematic for `VPATH` build and I suggest to use

```
$(OBJECTS): | build/.dirstamp
build/.dirstamp:
    mkdir ${@D}
```

here.

Comment: I managed to get this example to work by changing line 2 to `DLIBS=-ldl $(OPTLIBS)` and `tests: CFLAGS += $(TARGET)` to `tests: LDLIBS += $(TARGET)`. Make executes compile command assembled like this: "cc {CFLAGS} program.c {LDLIBS} -o program", in this exampple this is `cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -rdynamic -DNDEBUG tests/libex29_tests.c  -ldl build/libYOUR_LIBRARY.a -o tests/libex29_tests`